# Pandas match empty string or spaces

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In a large program, I found a bug that numbers were coming out as `NaN`. I'm having trouble understanding the cause.

In the context of this larger problem, the import data often is detected as object because there are may be blanks "" or spaces " ".  I want to change "" or " " (any number of spaces) to `np.nan`.  I want this to work whether the input is a series with one element or many, and if the element is numeric or string.

However, when I try the regex that seems obvious, it changes a valid number to NaN.  This is inside the debugger:

```
ipdb> temp_v1
value    1250.00
Name: standard, dtype: object
ipdb> temp_v1.replace(r"\s*", np.nan, regex=True)
value   NaN
Name: standard, dtype: float64
ipdb> type(temp_v1)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
ipdb> temp_v1.dtype
dtype('O')
ipdb> temp_v1.str.replace(r"\s*", np.nan, regex=True)
*** TypeError: repl must be a string or callable
ipdb> temp_v1.astype(str).replace(r"\s*", np.nan, regex=True)
value   NaN
Name: standard, dtype: float64
```

This is a simple mre for experimentation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.Series(['1250.00'])

x.replace(r"\s*", np.nan, regex=True)
```

When I run that, the output is NaN. Usually...

If I fiddle around in the terminal and try this over and over, it works correctly sometimes, but fails usually. This one succeeds, but I have no idea why.

```
In [19]: x = pd.Series(['123.44'])

In [20]: x.replace(r"\s*", "", regex=True)
Out[20]: 
0    123.44
dtype: object
```

Do same a few lines later, fail:

```
In [29]: x = pd.Series(['123.44'])

In [30]: x.replace(r'\s*', np.nan, regex=True)
Out[30]: 
0   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Seems like the XY problem... `replace` is not the correct tool for this, `pd.to_numeric` will succeed in turning non-numeric cells (empty spaces for instance) to `np.NaN`, and will convert those string representations `'123.44'` into actual numbers `123.44`

Comment: What is XY problem?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Basically, you're about debugging something about replace when really there's no reason to solve that problem in the first place because `replace` is irrelevant to how you _should_ solve the actual problem, which is likely, how to turn an Object column with non-numeric data to a numeric column with missing data replaced with np.NaN

Answer (score 2):

It appears that python is stumbling on the regex. It can successfully identify the regex for checking for spaces, but sees everything has "no space". If I replace the np.nan with the string "7" then I can see that the replace statement is replacing all of the empty space between characters (instead of just checking for an empty cell).

[image]

If I replace your regex with an "or" statement checking for spaces or a completely empty cell, then I get what you are wanting to see.

```
x = pd.Series(['1250.00','',' '])
x.replace(r'^\s*$| ', np.nan, regex=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this can be done without the additional pipe --> `x.replace(r"^\s*$", np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: I agree that changing the regex can solve the problem in this specific case.  @IanThompson revision is correct.  But why is this bozosity necessary?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to handle blank and multi-space strings (`""` or `"\s+"`) you can use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors="coerce"`

```
import pandas as pd  # version 1.1.5

x = pd.Series(["125.00", "", " ", "123.44"])

pd.to_numeric(x, errors="coerce")
```

Out

```
0    125.00
1       NaN
2       NaN
3    123.44
dtype: float64
```

Will also work if other string-values are present, though you may wish to inspect these further:

```
x = pd.Series(["125.00", "", " ", "123.44", "test"])

pd.to_numeric(x, errors="coerce")
```

Out

```
0    125.00
1       NaN
2       NaN
3    123.44
4       NaN
dtype: float64
```